# How to use Dropout and BatchNormalization in LSTM Networks (Keras)

Tags: keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, batch-normalization, dropout

I am using LSTM Networks for Multivariate Multi-Timestep predictions.
So basically `seq2seq` prediction where a number of `n_inputs` is fed into the model in order to predict a number of `n_outputs` of a time series.

My question is how to meaningfully apply `Dropout` and `BatchnNormalization` as this appears to be a highly discussed topic for Recurrent and therefore LSTM Networks. Lets stick to Keras as framework for the sake of simplicity.

**Case 1: Vanilla LSTM**

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(n_blocks, activation=activation, input_shape=(n_inputs, n_features), dropout=dropout_rate))
model.add(Dense(int(n_blocks/2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation(activation))
model.add(Dense(n_outputs))
```

- Q1: Is it good practice not to use BatchNormalization directly after
  LSTM layers?
- Q2: Is it good practice to use Dropout inside LSTM
  layer?
- Q3: Is the usage of BatchNormalization and Dropout between the
  Dense layers good practice?
- Q4: If I stack multiple LSTM layers, is it a good idea to use BatchNormalization between them?

**Case 2: Encoder Decoder like LSTM with TimeDistributed Layers**

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(n_blocks, activation=activation, input_shape=(n_inputs,n_features), dropout=dropout_rate))
model.add(RepeatVector(n_outputs))
model.add(LSTM(n_blocks, activation=activation, return_sequences=True, dropout=dropout_rate))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(int(n_blocks/2)), use_bias=False))
model.add(TimeDistributed(BatchNormalization()))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Activation(activation)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(dropout_rate)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
```

- Q5: Should `BatchNormalozation` and `Dropout` wrapped inside `TimeDistributed` layers when used between `TimeDistributed(Dense())` layers, or is it correct to leave them without?
- Q6: Can or should Batchnormalization be applied after, before, or in between the Encoder-Decoder LSTM Blocks?
- Q7: If a `ConvLSTM2D` layer is used as first Layer (Encoder) would this make a difference in the usage of Dropout and BatchNormalization?
- Q8: should the `recurrent_dropout` argument be used inside LSTM blocks? If yes should it be combined with normal `dropout` argument as it is in the example, or should it be exchanged?
  Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: `There are questions about recurrent_dropout vs dropout in LSTMCell, but as far as I understand this is not implemented in normal LSTM layer.` - I'd be interested in where you got this information from? Following, for example, the examples in F. Chollets book he uses and advises to set both since LSTM-dropout-calculation depends on it.

Comment: Furthermore, take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34716454/where-do-i-call-the-batchnormalization-function-in-keras. Some of your questions have been answered there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do I call the BatchNormalization function in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34716454/where-do-i-call-the-batchnormalization-function-in-keras)

Comment: @Markus no it is no duplicate, there are quite a few extra questions in it.
Furthermore the question is not how to apply batchnorm in keras in general, but how to apply it in lstm networks. With the recurrent_dropout you are right, I overread that, I will adjust the question.

Comment: Hmm when I read the answers in the linked post I do not see why they should not apply to LSTM (since the discussion was climaxing regarding the question wheather to normalize the input for the activation-function or layer-input, whereby the kind of layer was secondary).

Comment: There are multiple open questions on this topic. on stackoverflow e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45493384/is-it-normal-to-use-batch-normalization-in-rnn-lstm-rnn 
or somewhere else, e.g. https://www.quora.com/Why-is-it-difficult-to-apply-batch-normalization-to-RNNs