# What layers are affected by dropout layer in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning, dropout

Consider transfer learning in order to use a pretrained model in keras/tensorflow. For each old layer, `trained` parameter is set to `false` so that its weights are not updated during training whereas the last layer(s) have been substituted with new layers and these must be trained. Particularly two fully connected hidden layers with `512` and `1024` neurons and and relu activation function have been added. After these layers a Dropout layer is used with `rate` `0.2`. This means that during each epoch of training `20%` of the neurons are randomly discarded.

What layers does this dropout layer affect? Does it affect all the network including also the pretrained layers for which `layer.trainable=false` has been set or does it affect only the newly added layers? Or does it affect only the previous layer (i.e., the one with `1024` neurons)?

In other words, which layer(s) do the neurons that are turned off during each epoch by the dropout belong to?

```
import os

from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import Model
  
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3

local_weights_file = 'weights.h5'

pre_trained_model = InceptionV3(input_shape = (150, 150, 3), 
                                include_top = False, 
                                weights = None)

pre_trained_model.load_weights(local_weights_file)

for layer in pre_trained_model.layers:
  layer.trainable = False
  
# pre_trained_model.summary()

last_layer = pre_trained_model.get_layer('mixed7')
last_output = last_layer.output

# Flatten the output layer to 1 dimension
x = layers.Flatten()(last_output)
# Add two fully connected layers with 512 and 1,024 hidden units and ReLU activation
x = layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
# Add a dropout rate of 0.2
x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)                  
# Add a final sigmoid layer for classification
x = layers.Dense  (1, activation='sigmoid')(x)           

model = Model( pre_trained_model.input, x) 

model.compile(optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.0001), 
              loss = 'binary_crossentropy', 
              metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The dropout layer will affect the output of the previous layer.

If we look at the specific part of your code:

```
x = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
# Add a dropout rate of 0.2
x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)                  
# Add a final sigmoid layer for classification
x = layers.Dense  (1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
```

In your case, 20% of the output of the layer defined by `x = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)` will be dropped at random, before being passed to the final `Dense` layer.

Answer (score 4):

Only the *previous* layer's neurons are "turned off", but all layers are "affected" in terms of backprop.

- *Later layers*: Dropout's output is input to the next layer, so next layer's outputs will change, and so will next-next's, etc.
- *Previous layers*: as the "effective output" of the pre-Dropout layer is changed, so will gradients to it, and thus any subsequent gradients. In the extreme case of `Dropout(rate=1)`, zero gradient will flow.

Also, note that *whole neurons* are only dropped if input to Dense is 2D `(batch_size, features)`; Dropout applies a random uniform mask to all dimensions (equivalent to dropping whole neurons in 2D case). To drop whole neurons, set `Dropout(.2, noise_shape=(batch_size, 1, features))` (3D case). To drop *same* neurons across all samples, use `noise_shape=(1, 1, features)` (or `(1, features)` for 2D).

Comment: Sorry, the last part of your answer is unclear: what do you mean by `whole neurons` and by `if input is 2D`? do you mean two parameters or what?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi Every neuron outputs a tensor shaped `(batch_size, ...)`; if input is 3D, then it's `(batch_size, timesteps)`. If there are `features` neurons, the entire layer's output shape is `(batch_size, timesteps, features)`. A "whole neuron" is dropped if all of its outputs are zeroed - example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59294133/10133797) (at bottom): neuron 0, 5, and 11 are dropped.